# I have a few questions about white space, different browsers and image sizes for css

Tags: html, css

To begin with I have this 25% of a screen of white space when people open my page in chrome.

Finally, if I want an image to have the same size in different screens , should I include e.g. width="100%" height="50%" in the html.If yes , then why does w3 validator say that its not correct to use percentages.Also I think the white space mentioned above appeared after I removed those percentages.

I will post a link to my page bellow.

http://portfolio.rumen182.dk/

EDIT: I believe the problem only exists only for the small circle image(logome) and the first background image on the top(image2222).The problem is that the background one doesn't change it's width to adjust to other screen sizes so it just leaves white space and about the little logo image it just changes it's position I have no idea why.
*I'm pretty sure the image2222 css is not correct but I have no idea what else to do with it.*

```
</head>
<body>
    <div class="image2222">
        <img src="firstpage.png" alt="page" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav ph-line-nav">
        <a href="#">Home</a> 
        <a href="#aboutme">About</a> 
        <a href="#mywork">My Work</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <div class="effect"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="logome"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.image2222 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute no-rep
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;

}

.logome {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    right: 28%;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Finally, asking multiple questions at once is not recommended.

Comment: I didnt post the code because it can be accessed by just pressing cltr+u in the website , or am I mistaken?

Comment: SO policy is that yes, you are mistaken, for three main reasons; first, not all websites are built with plain HTML+CSS (most use server-side scripting); second, the code you have now will probably *change* once this question is answered, as I mentioned; third, the entire source code of your entire site is too large to be Minimal and too much to expect everyone to go through to answer. Trim it down out of respect for our time, please.

Comment: I'm sorry for all of this but this is literally my first ever post here (not that it's an excuse) but I have no idea where the problem in the code is for the website to be doing that, that's why I don't know what exactly to "trim down".

Comment: That's the best part: one of the key skills in debugging *any* code is to narrow down the area the bug is in, so you get to practice that! (The first link has some tips on how to go about that process, and you can doubtless find other help elsewhere as well.)

Comment: Okay I think I have an idea where it is coming from ,so should I just make a new question and delete this one somehow ? Thanks for the quick answers.

Comment: Nah, just [edit] this one to include the code and such.